# How do i join two tables and get data from both of the table to show to users on form field?

Tags: plsql

Table A (goradid) has a field which is a FK to Table B(Spriden). I need two sets of data (spriden_id and Goradid_additional_id) from Table A and Table B and insert it into one of the field called e.g. bannerid and partyid. please see my code below as i am also getting a error SQL command not properly ended in PLSQL.

```
SELECT  spriden_id, goradid_additional_id
            FROM goradid, spriden 
            INNER JOIN spriden ON spriden_pidm = goradid_pidm
            INTO bannerid, partyid;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `SELECT <COLUMN LIST> INTO <VARIABLE LIST>`. So the query should be:

```
SELECT spriden_id, goradid_additional_id
  INTO bannerid, partyid
  FROM goradid a INNER JOIN spriden b ON b.spriden_pidm = a.goradid_pidm;
```

Comment: for some reason i'm getting a error as "goradid_pidm" as invalid identifier.

Comment: Is there any column `goradid_pidm` in your table?

Comment: Yes. its in the table called Goradid and goradid_pidm is a column name

Comment: Use aliases for the tables. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aliasing for this.
it's simple.
SELECT spriden_id as bannerid, goradid_additional_id as partyid FROM goradid INNER JOIN spriden ON spriden_pidm = goradid_pidm;

Note: if you want to use into then you have to initialize the variable.
we use into usually.

```
 declare
  v_author author%rowtype;
 begin
select * into v_author from author where author_key = 'A103';
dbms_output.put_line('Name:'||v_author.author_first_name||' '||       v_author.author_last_name);
  end;
```